# Text Editor for Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, tinymce, javabeans

Can anyone please help me.I need to integrate a free text editor in my oracle forms. I know there's TinyMCE, but I can't figure out how to use it with JavaBeans.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly can't you figure out? You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: I downloaded tinyMCE and I want to enable it in my oracle form, I recognized it in the forms_path and the implementation class and all necessary steps but the toolbar is not showing...

Answer (score 1):

The Forms community is [a vast library of pluggable Java components](http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/), which are free.

There is at least one rich text editor component, Frite: [find it here](http://www.degenio.com/frite/).  No warranty is implied or intended.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already tried Frite, but it is not working.
it has 2 jar files none of which is called "com.degenio.frite.RteBean.jar" like the implementation class in oracle says it. I guess the downloaded file is missing this jar file or maybe I am doing something wrong, though i followed the developper's guide step by step.